# Reduce duplicate calls in Next js server side rendering

Tags: next.js13

Hi I am learning Next js and I love SSR.
But I dont know how to reduce some duplicate calls in generateMetadata() and Page(), if I need to call DB for some page info. It seems I need to call the DB twice in the 2 functions.

I just noticed in their official repo examples: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/2e3b88dcf120f9225656095710379e9b123f150b/examples/blog-starter/src/app/posts/%5Bslug%5D/page.tsx#L46, `getPostBySlug` was called twice in `generateMetadata` and `Post`. I suppose this is not resource efficient. But is there a better way to do this?

Find a way to call DB only once.

Answer (score 0):

According the official documentation this is not a concern. Our project uses `generateMetadata` and `Pages` calling the same RSC with >90 Lighthouse Performance.

The React Server Component is cached in the [Full Router Cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#full-route-cache) and returns the cached payload when available.

As an alternative you could look into adding the metadata with HTML tags when that fits your purpose. There are packages available.

Comment: but will this actually mean 2 DB queries for the same info?